# iTunes is not syncing my phone

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, itunes, mac

I cannot pull up the summary tab or view info on my phone via iTunes, and I also cannot sync my phone with my computer.

[image]

[image: How can I solve this?]

Comment: What's shown on your device screen? Looks like the device is in recovery mode.

Comment: there is nothing shown on device screen...

Comment: Please try unlocking the phone and pressing 'trust this computer' on the popup.

Comment: Go to menu Account -> Authorize and authorize this computer. You need to enter your Apple ID password. Check if the sync still greyed out on your devices.

Comment: @Jackson1442,  I already did this but not working.

Comment: @dante12, I tried this but still it shows gray out the sync option.

Comment: Have you ever synced this phone with a different computer?

Comment: @Jackson1442, May be yes because I purchase second hand iPhone :)

Comment: @nirav did you have to complete the setup assistant when you got the phone? (high white "hello" screen)